# Sed script inserting and appending in wrong place only in one particular place

Tags: sed, conversion, latex, ascii

I am trying to convert man pages to tex, and I keep getting

```
\item[
```

in the beginning of the file and

```
] \hfill \\
```

After the part of the man pages where it shows ENV(1L). Everything else seems to be working.

This is my tex.sed:

```
/^\<[A-Z]*[A-Z]/i \
\\item[

/^\<[A-Z]*[A-Z]/a \
] \\hfill \\\\

1i\
\\documentstyle[11pt]{article} \
\\begin{document}


1i\
\\begin{center} {\\bf 

1a\
\} \\end{center}


2i\
\\begin{description}

$a\
\\end{description}

$a\
\\end{document}


s/\\/\\verb\+\\\+/g
s/%/\\%/g
s/\^/\\\^/g
s/--/-\\hspace\{.01cm\}-/g

s/^+/ \\\\/
s/^-/ \\\\/
```

Here is env.ascii:

```
ENV(1L)


NAME
      env - run a program in a modified environment

SYNOPSIS
      env    [-]    [-i]    [-u   name]   [--ignore-environment]
      [--unset=name] [name=value]... [command [args...]]

DESCRIPTION
      This manual page documents the GNU version  of  env.   env
      runs  a  command with an environment modified as specified
      by the command line  arguments.   Arguments  of  the  form
      `variable=value'  set the environment variablevariable to
      valuevalue.  value may be empty (`variable=').  Setting a
      variable to an empty value is different from unsetting it.

      The  first  remaining  argument  specifies  a  program  to
      invoke;  it is searched for according to the specification
      of the PATH environment variable.  Any arguments following
      that are passed as arguments to that program.

      If  no command name is specified following the environment
      specifications,  the  resulting  environment  is  printed.
      This is like specifying a command name of `printenv'.

OPTIONS
     -u, --unset name
             Remove  variable name  from the environment, if it
             was in the environment.

     -, -i, --ignore-environment
             Start  with  an  empty  environment,  ignoring  the
             inherited environment.

      The  long-named options can be introduced with `+' as well
      as `--', for compatibility with previous releases.   
      Eventually  support  for  `+'  will  be removed, because it 
      is incompatible with the POSIX.2 standard.
```

And this is how I am compiling:

```
sed -f tex.sed env.ascii > env.tex
```

This is what my env.tex looks like:

```
\documentstyle[11pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
\begin{center} {\bf 
\item[
ENV(1L)
] \hfill \\
} \end{center}
\begin{description}


\item[
NAME
] \hfill \\
      env - run a program in a modified environment

\item[
SYNOPSIS
] \hfill \\
      env    [-]    [-i]    [-u   name]   [-\hspace{.01cm}-ignore-environment]
      [-\hspace{.01cm}-unset=name] [name=value]... [command [args...]]

\item[
DESCRIPTION
] \hfill \\
      This manual page documents the GNU version  of  env.   env
      runs  a  command with an environment modified as specified
      by the command line  arguments.   Arguments  of  the  form
      `variable=value'  set the environment variablevariable to
      valuevalue.  value may be empty (`variable=').  Setting a
      variable to an empty value is different from unsetting it.

      The  first  remaining  argument  specifies  a  program  to
      invoke;  it is searched for according to the specification
      of the PATH environment variable.  Any arguments following
      that are passed as arguments to that program.

      If  no command name is specified following the environment
      specifications,  the  resulting  environment  is  printed.
      This is like specifying a command name of `printenv'.

\item[
OPTIONS
] \hfill \\
     -u, --unset name
             Remove  variable name  from the environment, if it
             was in the environment.

     -, -i, --ignore-environment
             Start  with  an  empty  environment,  ignoring  the
             inherited environment.

      The  long-named options can be introduced with `+' as well
      as `-\hspace{.01cm}-', for compatibility with previous releases.   
      Eventually  support  for  `+'  will  be removed, because it 
      is incompatible with the POSIX.2 standard.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

**Note**

The end result must be a `sed` script that correctly converts the man page to a `.tex` file. Please don't suggest answers with a different approach to the problem.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: It must be a sed script

Comment: @MarcusLorenzana I edited the question based on your clarification. Feel free to roll back the edit and re-phrase it in your own words. It's generally helpful to edit the question and specify any additional requirements even if you've mentioned them in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your desired result is just the man pages in PDF format, `man` itself can do this for you. You will need the `ghostscript` suite of tools and you can do the following, for example, to get the `bash(1)` page in PDF format:

```
man -T ps bash|ps2pdf - bash.pdf
```

If you were intending to use LaTeX to produce DVI man pages, you won't need `ghostscript` as `man` can do this directly:

```
man -T dvi bash >bash.dvi
```

**Quoted verbatim from Bichoy's comment**

> The -T ps option is not portable for man. On RHEL6, the correct syntax will be man -t bash, the -t option makes the output as ps using /usr/bin/groff -Tps -mandoc

**A few notes about the `sed` script**

- What worked for me is moving the first 6 lines of your script after the `\\begin{center}` line. Please try it and see if this is the desired result.
- You should put considerable effort into escaping special characters in the content of the man page(s). Your script currently escapes some of them but there's always a chance you're forgetting one or another. I can tell you at least forgot to escape ampersands (`&`) which (La)TeX uses as column separators. This is why umläute and I have been suggesting an alternate approach to TeXifying the whole thing yourself.
- Is the beginning of your document a typo or is it actually supposed to be `\\documentstyle` as opposed to `\\documentclass`?
- To exclude the command name from being surrounded by `\item` tags, you should change your regex to match a word consisting entirely of uppercase letters: change `\<[A-Z]*[A-Z]` to something like `^\s*[A-Z][A-Z]*\s*$`.

Comment: The `-T ps` option is not portable for man.
On RHEL6, the correct syntax will be `man -t bash`, the `-t` option makes the output as `ps` using `/usr/bin/groff -Tps -mandoc`.

Comment: That definitely seems like a better option but yeah it has to be a sed script

Comment: @Bichoy Thanks for the feedback. Answer updated.

Comment: @MarcusLorenzana Answer updated. Please see if this helps.

Comment: That seemed to have fixed that bit, but now I am getting a \item[ before ENV(1L) and the ] \hfill \\. How would I modify the command so that it skips the words that contain "ENV(1L)" or in other man pages such as  "FIND(1L)".

Comment: Looks kind of hard to read in the comments, I will update my env.tex

Comment: @MarcusLorenzana Answer updated.

Comment: Now I am not getting anymore \item tags. I had tried something similar before, like ^\<[A-Z]*[A-Z]$ but it also would make the \item tags disappear.

Comment: Actually now I'm noticing that the output file when I do "sed -f ascii.sed env.1 > env.ascii" env.ascii looks the same as env.1

Comment: I was using cat to check the output files before, I guess that was a bad idea

Comment: Ended up I was doing the wrong sed command when I converted env.1 to env.ascii. I was trying to remove the '^H' from the file and I had to use vi editor and do CTRL+V then CTRL+H in the substitution. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @MarcusLorenzana You're most welcome. Glad to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

have you checked a troff-to-latex converter like [tr2latex](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/support/tr2latex/)?

it might do exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: It must be a sed script